# Where clause with dateformat and other variables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `siparisler` WHERE `cafe_id` = 3 AND DATE_FORMAT(tarih,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 2017-08-01 AND 2017-08-06
```

My dates are listed like this on my table  (tarih) 2017-02-22 15:28:33
so I want to retrieve data when cafe_id is 3 and tarih between those two dates.

But when I run this query I get zero results.
What may be the problem. I could not find any solution.

Comment: Enclose dates in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT()` is used on a date data type.  You don't need it.  You only need the quotes around the constants:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM siparisler s
WHERE s.cafe_id = 3 AND
      s.tarih >= '2017-08-01' AND
      s.tarih < '2017-08-07'
```

Note that I changed the condition from `BETWEEN` to direct comparisons.  This is on purpose.  This logic will work regardless of whether `tarih` has a time component.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to quote the date string literal. It should be

```
BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-06'
```